# C++ binary search tree template class memory leak

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, binary-search-tree

Newbie question.  I am trying to program a binary search tree, but even
a simple insert has a memory leak.

File Node.h

```
template<typename X> struct Node {
   X value;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;

   Node(X x) {
      this->value = x;
      this->left = nullptr;
      this->right = nullptr;
   }
};
```

File BST.h

```
template <typename X> class BST {
   public:
      BST() { root = nullptr; }

      bool Insert(const X& x) { return InsertAt(root, x); }

   private:

      bool InsertAt(Node<X>*& node, const X& x)
      {
         if (node == nullptr) {
            node = new Node<X>(x);
            return true;
         }

         if (node->value == x)
            return false;

         if (*(node->value) > *x)
            return InsertAt(node->left, x);

         return InsertAt(node->right, x);
      }

//----

      Node<X>* root;
};
```

The main program

```
#include "Node.h"
#include "BST.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   BST<int*> bst;
   bst.Insert(new int(8));
}
```

The output of g++ -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 B.cpp 
    ==10646==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

```
Direct leak of 24 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fb5e7f45532 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x99532)
    #1 0x400eb7 in BST<int*>::InsertAt(Node<int*>*&, int* const&) /home/gc/BST.h:12
    #2 0x400e68 in BST<int*>::Insert(int* const&) /home/gc/BST.h:5
    #3 0x400d09 in main /home/gc/B.cpp:22
    #4 0x7fb5e778082f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)

Indirect leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fb5e7f45532 in operator new(unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x99532)
    #1 0x400caf in main /home/gc/B.cpp:22
    #2 0x7fb5e778082f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 28 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

First, why am I getting a memory leak?  Second, why am I getting a message
about new(unsigned long) when there is nothing unsigned long about my program?
Thanks.

You may tell me to use smart pointers, but for right now I'm just trying to
educate myself about pointers and trying to figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: You aren't gonna accept my answer? :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use smart pointers, then you have to pair every `new` with a `delete`.  Since your calls to `new` happen in each class's constructor, you can `delete` in the destructor.

Anyways, in `BST` the destructor should be

```
~BST() { delete root; }
```

And in `Node`, it's

```
~Node() { delete left; delete right; }
```

This will recursively work it's way down the tree.  Your recursive case is when a pointer to a node is not null.  Unlike with `free` which crashes on a null, `delete` simply does nothing, making `nullptr` your base case.

Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor

Comment: And yes, it is obligatory that I tell you to just use `std::unique_ptr<Node<X>>` instead of worrying about `new` and `delete`.  It saves on lines of code, it makes your intent obvious, and then there's that whole "exception safety" issue.

Comment: Also, I just found that since in this case, value is a pointer, I also need `delete value` in `~Node()`.